# Made-For-TV movie similar to or based on RIPD story before it became a feature film

Tags: story-identification, tv

Did the SciFi channel (before it became SyFy) or anyone else do a version of the story that was made into the movie R.I.P.D.? There was the spirit of an L.A. detective who died in the 1940's and his newly-dead partner going after an "inverse karmic mutation" that was possessing the body of a housewife. Everything in the spirit world seemed retro. The "ambulance" (which could go through walls) was a vehicle from the 40's or maybe the 30's. The detective was wearing a zoot suit.

I remember watching it on a local TV station that ran a lot of science fiction.

Comment: Are you thinking of [Brimstone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brimstone_(TV_series))?

Comment: No, this was a made for TV movie that was shown not on the SCI-FI channel but on a local channel that featured SCI-Fi channel movies. The story was pretty much as described, a newly-dead cop teamed with one that died in the 1940's. The old cop wore a zoot suit, and everything in the spirit world was more than a bit retro. The "ambulance" (which could go through walls) was a vehicle from the 40's or maybe the 30's. By the way I liked Brimstone a lot.

Comment: I remember watching segments of that movie as well, and thought i can watch it again at some later date because the channel who aired that movie used to air all the movies many times. But the R.I.P.D old version dosent seem to exist anymore they only aired that movie one time and it seems to be gone from existance. I have tried to find that movie for many years and it dosent exist anymore. Perhaps it might have a connection to the mandela effect. Things get altered or dissapear.I live in Sweden and watch it on a Swedish tv channel.